# Response in akka using ask pattern

Tags: scala, akka

i trying get response from my actor using ask pattern
in ask response i have `List(scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable@33d40b3)`
but i expect get string "1,2"
How i can get expected results ?

this is my code:

```
class Storage extends Actor {
  var map:ListBuffer[List[String]] = new ListBuffer
  val logger = Logging(context.system,this)

  override def receive = {
    case setRequest(url, urlType)=>
      map+=List(  url, urlType)
      logger.info(s"Putting ${url} to storage")
      sender() ! Status.Success

    case getRequest()=>
      if (map.length >=1){
        var response= map(0).mkString(",")
        logger.info(s"Send ${response}")
        map = map.filter(x => x != response)
        sender ! response
      }
      else{
        sender()! Status.Failure(new emptyStorage)
      }
    case getLength()=>
      sender()! map.length
  }
}

object Main extends  App{
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  val system = ActorSystem.create("default-dispatcher", ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("MyDispatcherExample"))
  val storage = system.actorOf(Props(new Storage))
  storage ! setRequest("1", "2")
  val result = Future {storage ? getRequest }
  result onComplete{
    case Success(result)=> println(result)
    case Failure(result)=> println("some  error")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ask pattern by itself returns a `Future` which you're wrapping in an additional `Future` giving us `Future[Future[Any]]`. There's not need for that:

```
val result = storage ? getRequest 
result onComplete {
  case Success(res) => println(res)
  case Failure(e) => println(e)
}
```

Additionally, when you pass data around in Akka, especially generic data types which are subject to type erasure, it is recommended to wrap them in a case class. For example:

```
case class Response(result: String)
```

It is also that a `Future` returned by ask is untyped. It is recommended to use `mapTo` in order to cast to a typed response:

```
val result: Future[Response] = (storage ? getRequest).mapTo[Response]
```

Comment: in first case a have AskTimeoutException with message: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://default-dispatcher/user/$a#1016813778]] after [5000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "main.scala.messages.getRequest$".

Comment: Did you debug the `getRequest` method on your storage actor? Is it returning the data to the sender?

Comment: logger.info(s"Send ${response}") print my sending list

Comment: i dont know because, but i find a problem in statement: if (map.length >=1). When i delete this code part all is ok